# Why ORC can support acid in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, parquet, orc

I have read the documentation that says

```
"Only ORC file format is supported in this first release.  The feature has been built such that transactions can be used by any storage format that can determine how updates or deletes apply to base records (basically, that has an explicit or implicit row id), but so far the integration work has only been done for ORC."
```

But my question is that why only ORC, why it can't be done for parquet for instance, does ORC have something special that makes it compatible for ACID transactions?

Answer (score 0):

As per `cwiki`,

> Only ORC file format is supported in this first release.  The feature has been built such that transactions can be used by any storage format that can determine how updates or deletes apply to base records (basically, that has an explicit or implicit row id), but so far the integration work has only been done for ORC.

ORC doesnt have anything special except columnar storage, zipped file format - which makes it fast over text files. Theoretically doable.
This feature came in 2014 for version 0.13. After that, they have improved the functionality but not for other file formats. Which means, there may not be enough demand or complex for other file format or they have to rewrite everything for other file formats.

You can refer to this link for more details on the transactional feature.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/hive+transactions